# Raspberry Pi - Remote / Attached Access - Plug and Play

Tags: linux, raspbian-stretch, remote

OK

I wont go into the reasoning apart from the fact that I need to find or research and create an EASY Plug and Play solution to enable Raspberry Pis to be used in a classroom environment.

Criteria are that the teacher and the pupils are complete novices and no nothing about ssh / IP addresses / VNC etc, etc.

So what I am researching is the ability to plug a Raspberry Pi into a host device i.e. a Laptop and simply by opening an icon / app on the host device the user can have full access to the Raspbian Desktop. Voila - simples!!

HDMI to USB is a possibility, as is keyboard and mouse sharing, so hardware and software wise with the Raspberry Pi is this possible?

Your input would be thankfully received

Comment: I think this might depend on the individual laptop. That is to say, I would tend to doubt that there's a "one size fits all" adapter that you could plug into any laptop, and get the HDMI output from the RPi displayed on its monitor. But if they're all the same type of laptop, once you found a solution, it would be easier to implement.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple, keep it simple. Connect the Pi to a monitor or projector using HDMI, plug in a USB keyboard and mouse and turn the Pi on.

Comment: This is fine if you have a dedicated IT suite in a school where you can set the Pis up. Oh and if you have a whole load of spare monitors, keyboards and mice :-) We have neither. All we have is 4 trolleys of 14 laptops which are in high demand, hence the need to be able to plug them into a laptop and easily.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to know anything about VNC to use it (maybe only one time to configure it). Create a desktop icon on the laptop to start VNC. Then just connect the RasPi with an ethernet cable to the laptop. On the RasPi with default Raspbian the wired network connection is working out of the box. You don't tell us what operating system there is running on the laptops. Maybe there is a bit configuration required to get the connection. With a pre configured VNC server on the RasPi just click the desktop icon on the laptop and Voila - you have full access to the Raspbian Desktop.